# How to do edit text content keeping it in a CDATA block?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml, xelement

I want to edit the contents of a cdata block in this an document. Here's a simplified example:

```
<root><![CDATA[pi > 22/7]]></root>
```

I tried

```
var element = XElement.Parse("<root><![CDATA[pi > 22/7]]></root>");
element.Value = element.Value.Replace("> 22/7", "< 22/7");
element.Dump();
```

However, the result doesn't have a CDATA block.

```
<root>pi &lt; 22/7</root>
```

I wanted

```
<root><![CDATA[pi < 22/7]]></root>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify value of the [XCData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element instead :

```
var element = XElement.Parse("<root><![CDATA[pi > 22/7]]></root>");
var cdata = (XCData)element.FirstNode;
cdata.Value = cdata.Value.Replace("> 22/7", "< 22/7");
element.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with

```
var newValue = element.Value.Replace("> 22/7", "< 22/7");
element.ReplaceNodes(new XCData(newValue));
```